# React - body not full height

Tags: css, reactjs

I know there are other questions like this, but none of them helped me

I can't make body tag full height, there is a white space before and after body tag

App.css:

```
html, body, #root{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Also tried:

```
    html, {
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
    }

    body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you have an element inside the body having a default margin (the `ul`) (add `overflow:hidden` to the body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The un-ordered list (`<ul>`) have a margin set by default. Have you tried removing that margin?

```
.menu-links {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing margin and padding from html and body tag.

Try to see if the element inside the body does not have also a margin.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

A little demo https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-meadow-tysfm

I case of using the ul > li they have default margin as stated below.

Comment: thanks, but did not solve it